# Plotting time intervals by day in R

Tags: r, time, plot

I have a `nx2` dataframe where each row contains beginning and end of some time interval.

```
              start                 end
3  2015-04-21 20:57:23 2015-04-21 23:55:23
5  2015-04-22 00:16:26 2015-04-22 00:28:23
8  2015-04-22 01:20:14 2015-04-22 02:34:51
12 2015-04-22 03:31:27 2015-04-22 04:31:03
14 2015-04-22 04:35:56 2015-04-22 05:54:10
16 2015-04-22 06:01:35 2015-04-22 07:14:35
```

I would like to plot these intervals in R with x-axis being 24 hours and y-axis being days. So it should look something like this:

[image]

What is the appropriate way to do this?

Here's dput from the first 20 rows:

```
nx2 <- structure(list(start = structure(c(1429642643.153, 1429654586.936, 
1429658414.048, 1429666287.926, 1429670156.358, 1429675295.181, 
1429680010.595, 1429691755.137, 1429700624.139, 1429708239.758, 
1429712967.668, 1429716686.314, 1429725292.357, 1429735963.053, 
1429741262.112, 1429751626.278, 1429755842.324, 1429774600.104, 
1429787329.274, 1429791813.291), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), end = structure(c(1429653323.153, 1429655303.968, 
1429662891.218, 1429669863.373, 1429674850.654, 1429679675.181, 
1429686495.759, 1429695163.947, 1429707547.129, 1429711839.758, 
1429715565.467, 1429722206.314, 1429734763.081, 1429740231.567, 
1429749242.112, 1429752556.557, 1429767902.324, 1429783522.586, 
1429790609.476, 1429795064.659), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "")), .Names = c("start", "end"), row.names = c(3L, 
5L, 8L, 12L, 14L, 16L, 18L, 24L, 28L, 30L, 33L, 35L, 38L, 42L, 
44L, 48L, 52L, 59L, 65L, 68L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you add output of `dput(nx2)` to you post?

Comment: added output of dput from first 20 rows

Comment: I want to see how these intervals change from day to day. So I want to have a set of e.g. white horizontal lines (or stripes) where each line corresponds to some calendar day from 0:00:00 till 23:59:59 and some parts of each line should be colored blue to show intervals from the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way doing it using ggplot and dplyr. The graph is displayed for **Moscow time**.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

tz <- "Europe/Moscow"

df <- nx2 %>%
  mutate( hour_start = floor(as.numeric(start)/3600),
          hour_end_est = ceiling(as.numeric(end)/3600),
          hour_end = ifelse(hour_end_est >= hour_start, 
                            hour_end_est,
                            hour_start)
  ) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do( {
    hourstamp <- 3600 * seq( .$hour_start, .$hour_end, by=1) 
    day_hour <- sapply(hourstamp, function(x) 
                as.POSIXlt(x, tz=tz, origin="1970-01-01")$hour)
    day_id <- sapply(hourstamp, function(x)
                as.POSIXlt(x, tz=tz, origin="1970-01-01")$mday)
    data.frame(hour = day_hour, day = day_id)    
  } ) 


ggplot(df,aes(x=hour, y=day))  +
  geom_tile(col="black",fill="blue",alpha=0.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:24,limits=c(-1,24)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:31,limits=c(-1,31)) +
  xlab("Hours") +
  ylab("Days")
```

And I get this:
[image]

If minute resolution is needed then it is a simple modification to the code above:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

tz <- "Europe/Moscow"

df <- nx2 %>%
  mutate( minute_start = floor(as.numeric(start)/60),
          minute_end_est = ceiling(as.numeric(end)/60),
          minute_end = ifelse(minute_end_est >= minute_start, 
                            minute_end_est,
                            minute_start)
  ) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do( {
    minutestamp <- 60 * seq( .$minute_start, .$minute_end, by=1) 
    day_minute <- sapply(minutestamp, function(x) 
      {
        psx_time <- as.POSIXlt(x, tz=tz, origin="1970-01-01")
        psx_time$hour*60 + psx_time$min
      })
    day_id <- sapply(minutestamp, function(x)
      {
        psx_time <- as.POSIXlt(x, tz=tz, origin="1970-01-01")
        psx_time$mday
      })
    data.frame(minute = day_minute, day = day_id)    
  } ) 


ggplot(df,aes(x=minute, y=day))  +
  geom_tile(fill="blue",alpha=0.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,24*60,by=60),
                     limits=c(-60,24*60)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:31,limits=c(-1,31)) +
  xlab("Minutes") +
  ylab("Days")
```

And I get this:

[image]

Comment: Error in seq.default(.$hour_start, .$hour_end, by = 1) : 
  wrong sign in 'by' argument

Comment: Oops.. forgot to add libraries: `library(ggplot2)` and `library(dplyr)`

Comment: By the way, is start always smaller than end?

Comment: I guess, this error happens when the beginning of some interval is at the end of one day and its end is at the beginning of next day.

Comment: This is unlikely since it is accounted for. It looks like the full data set contains data points when start timestamp > end timestamp. I added a check for that. Please try if that works!

Comment: There was one last row without end, maybe that was the problem. This code does what I want, thank you so much! I removed any mention of time zone since I'm okay with what I have. And I wonder if it's possible to have x-axis signed with hours. It would be easier to understand what is going on than to divide current breaks in mind by 60.

Comment: That's why I love ggplot! This is just 1 line change. Just add "labels" to scale_x_continuous: `scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(0,24*60,by=60),
                     limits=c(-60,24*60),
                     labels=seq(0,24))`

Comment: Yes, this is really cool. Guess I should complete some ggplot tutorial. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77290/discussion-between-egor-ignatenkov-and-akhmed).

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)

#data prep for plotting
nx2$DD <- day(nx2$start)
nx2$startHH <- hour(nx2$start)
nx2$endHH <- hour(nx2$end)

#plot    
ggplot(nx2,aes(xmin = startHH, xmax = endHH + 1,
               ymin = DD-0.5, ymax = DD + 0.5)) +
  geom_rect(col="black",fill="blue",alpha=0.3) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks=0:24,limits=c(0,24)) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=0:31,limits=c(0,31)) +
  xlab("Hours") +
  ylab("Days") +
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: This is actually very nice, thank you very much! But what if I want minute-precision? It seems that if I color the whole hour-intervals, I get colored almost everything.

Comment: It looks like there is some issue. The plot shows no activity for two  hours right after midnight 23rd yet the data suggests that this is not true. (rownames 35, 38, 42, 44, 48)

Comment: Very nice. How would this approach work if a period spans more than one day" e.g. started one day at say 10:07 PM and ended the following day at 6 AM?